# How to alter date format in page header in Kate (kde text editor)

Tags: format, kate

In Kate, I can specify the headers to appear on each printed page:

File > Print... > Options > Header & Footer

In the Header Properties, I found the Format code `%y` in the left field. This yields the date in the header in the format `1/19/19`. I'd like to use a different format.

After some trial and error, I found some date/time related formats:

```
%y => 1/19/19
%Y => Saturday, January 19, 2019
%t => %t
%T => %T
%i => %i
%I => %I
%d => 1/19/19 4:59 PM
%D => Saturday, January 19, 2019 4:49:58 PM CET
```

(I tried `t` for time, `i` for ISO, `d` for day)

I would like to use the ISO-format, preferably *with* the time: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`.

Unfortunately, there is no "help" button listing the formats and the Kate manual is silent on this subject. I tried to look this up on the internet, but no success there so far...

I am on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04.5 LTS) with LXDE.

Comment: By the way, are you still using the OS mentioned here or have you moved to Kubuntu? Even on Kubuntu 18.04, there's not much you can do re. changing the header format. Apparently, Kate uses the locale settings: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/75245-Formatting-the-date-in-Kate-s-print-header

Comment: Yes, I am currently on Kubuntu 18.04.2. Kate using the locale settings is not bad per se, **if** I could set those properly. I have now set the Time format to `Sweden (en_SE)`. I consider this a non-solution or workaround as I am not in Sweden. I also found the setting `Default (C)`, which might suggest that I could install some locale based on ISO standards?

Comment: It maybe possible to run kate with a locale different than your default locale. Does `LANG=en_SE kate` help? If it does, you can create a shortcut/desktop file to always start kate that way.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but didn't work. Perhaps because I do not have that locale installed. Also, it is not installable: `$ sudo locale-gen en_SE` returns `Error: 'en_SE' is not a supported language or locale`. Do you know of a specific ISO-locale (not tied to any country / language) that I might install? NB: I never want to use `24-03-19`, `19/03/24`, `3/24/19` and the like on my system: ALWAYS `2019-03-24` (ISO) is what I want.

Comment: Oh! I thought you had it installed. By the way, Geany allows you better customization and obeys the formats described in `man date`. So, `%F %H:%M` would give you what you want.

Comment: This is a print to pdf from Geany: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgZOc.png

Answer (score 1):

(I can't comment, so I'll add an answer instead.) 
Kate is a KDE programme and depends on Qt.  Somebody in Qt decided everyone in locale must use the formats for that locale. You must use the settings for your locale, and also, they **compile in** the settings for each locale, so you can't modify the file in /usr/share/i18n/locales to fix things, nor add a new locale.

Comment: Here's something with a lot of background: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/8096tl/q_kde5kubuntu_1604_am_i_totally_stupid_or_is_it/

Comment: Interesting reads. I guess I am now looking for some generic locale (in Qt, apparently) which uses ISO date/time formats, with English day and month names. Does anyone have a link to the Qt source code where all locales are hard-coded?

Answer (score -1):

*Any luck or update?*

This has been a moderate annoyance since KDE4... Everyone says the same thing, but nobody listens to the user base and fixes it.

Of course, having an option tied direction to what is in **date** would make a lot of sense.  Yeah, locale is handy and will be a nice default, but if I wanted all my configuration and customization done by some corporation I would be using OS/X!